# Problem: Character with backpack (physics)

Tags: animation, rigidbody

I have a rigged character, for which I am trying to design a backpack, which should bounce around a little when running.

But I am lost with the “physics”, as I am new to blender. I tried to design the backpack as rigid body. Even when I add rigid body constrains to my rigged character, I cannot get it working.

Is there any other way to solve it.

Even if I could not get it bouncing, if it follows the body propery without merging/overlapping with the character, it would be fine for now.

Can somebody help me out. Even a reference to a tutorial video would be welcome. I was not able to find any for this topic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I saw in the past a video about a handbag doing exacltly what you want, but i cant find it now, i think it is the same in this other video series where daniel kreuter uses rigid bodies and bones for the hair, hope it helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10hgRL6D1qU

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it